# qt creator on mac, missing project templates

Tags: macos, qt

I'm sure there must be a simple explanation, I have downloaded the latest sdk and installed it using default settings in 10.7.5. I've used QT on windows before so I know how to make a project, however when I try and make a project expecting something like this to appear:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtcreator/images/qtcreator-new-qt-quick-project-wizard.png

But this is what I actually see:

http://trollfx.com/qt_whatisee.jpg

There are no gui project available, also none of the samples are present on the welcome page. searching for them just does nothing. I'm completely stumped, can anyone advise please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I think what you've done is you've downloaded QtCreator as a stand alone app, and you're missing the actual Qt base files.

Uninstall QtCreator and then go to http://qt-project.org/downloads and download Qt itself, which comes with QtCreator bundled with it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have correctly configured the directory where Qt is installed. It needs to know where to find the `qmake` utility. (Specifically, go to Preferences|Build & Run|Qt Versions, click Add and locate the qmake executable).

Btw, it is assumed that you have installed XCode (at least its Unix command-line development tools.) In contrast to Windows, the Mac version does not come with a compiler. You need XCode for that.